# Using clientside javascript with Rules

Tags: javascript, rules

I would like to implement a client side javascript action using the Rules module. Has anybody been able to do this?

Comment: Rules are processed on the server side, not client side, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am using a javascript to open a local program (e.g. text editor) with the click of a button. The javascript is given an argument (e.g. location of a textfile), which is stored and retrieved from the Drupal site. This I have already implemented and it works. (I use an extension to allow executing local code using the XPCOM interface. I am aware of the security implications.) I now wish to use Rules in conjunction with VBO and Views in order to, for example, open a series of files with the texteditor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules is not designed to work with client side events. They way Rules is designed, it won't make any sense to try to make it aware of client side events.

Your best course of action would be to write some custom JavaScript.

If you want to add some javascript code to a page using rules, that would be possible if you created a custom action that added the JavaSript you wanted to the site.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been more eloquent, my fault. I think I did exactly what you said. I have written custom javascript code, and I wish to call this code up at certain moments using Rules. In essence, I want to choose a number of entities (using checkboxes from VBO on a Views table), and perform the javascript on these entities. Rules gives me the possibility to add a VBO action: I would like to use Rules to enable my custom javascript code for a VBO action.  I hope I am not being too convoluted.

Comment: I think you (googletorp) phrased it better than I did: I need to know how to add a custom action which calls on my javascript code.

Comment: .. and using the "Custom PHP action" does not seem to do the job.

Comment: @Punchy If you explain what you are trying to achieve, we could probably understand your question a bit better. My hunch is what you want to do is impossible or the wrong approach.

Comment: You're right, here goes: I have a database in which I store the local coordinates of scientific measurements. I use views (tabular) to list and filter the measurements. I would like to choose some measurements, and open the files associated with them with the click of a button. The directories where these files reside (on my local PC) are given in the database. I already have custom javascript code which can open the files with the appropriate software. I would now like to be able to open the measurements from my views table.. (I thought VBO would be a good option.)

Comment: @Punchy You shouldn't use VBO for that. VBO is for doing stuff like mass deleting/updating content etc, not displaying files. What you need to do, is to tell what files the javascipt needs to open, this can be done in a hidden field, a class etc. Rules and VBO is not useful for this at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that feedback. Could you maybe point me in the direction of how I would go about initiating the javascript code execution? Could I somehow put a link or button in each row of the views table, and have the javascript execute for the data in that row ? That would be ideal. I realize this thread is straying, sorry.

Comment: @Punchy You should post a new question, comments doesn't fit asking/answering questions.